# Express ES6 config issue

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I can not get the following to compile, and I don't know why. I am using ES6 syntax to import all the things in server.ts

Node 14

package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Matthew Reynolds",
  "license": "Proprietary",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "server": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import Express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
const app = Express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server Ready");
}).on('error', (e: any) => {
    console.log("Server Error");
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2015",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015",                       /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

I can't run the server target:

```
Compilation error in /Users/workspace/api/server.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/workspace/api/server.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/workspace/api/server.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module._compile (/Users/workspace/api/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/private/var/folders/p0/xbzc_v4x2xgccqxk0rh2f8k00000gp/T/ts-node-dev-hook-5362012710629007.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/private/var/folders/p0/xbzc_v4x2xgccqxk0rh2f8k00000gp/T/ts-node-dev-hook-5362012710629007.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/private/var/folders/p0/xbzc_v4x2xgccqxk0rh2f8k00000gp/T/ts-node-dev-hook-5362012710629007.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/Users/workspace/api/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
[ERROR] 18:27:34 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/workspace/api/server.ts
```

What am I missing? I have tried tweaking everything...This system wants more text so I have to keep typing useless words so that I can save this post.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `type: module` but `ts-node` uses CJS by default. You can either switch to using CJS or adding the configuration for ESM.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "ts-node": {
    // Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically, explained below
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#commonjs-vs-native-ecmascript-modules